# How to remove column without downtime with ActiveRecord 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Removing columns from tables while running application with ActiveRecord causes errors, because ActiveRecord caches column names.

Workaround for other versions of ActiveRecord is to override #columns method in the model and filter out deprecated column names before migration (basically - hide these columns from AR). This worked because all column name related methods were based on #columns call

In ActiveRecord 3.1 caching of table structures is moved to ConnectionPool, and all column name related values (e.g. coluumns_hash) are cached independently  (3.2 uses ModelSchema.columns that made this working again)

Is there any way (other than deep-hack of concrete adapters) to achieve safe column drop in ActiveRecord 3.1?

Comment: It there a specific reason why not firstly get rid of the code using the column and deploy it? You could remove the column in a subsequent migration then.

Comment: When you e.g. save a record, AR issues a SQL statement that explicitly sets all column values. So it does not matter whether your code uses column or not - underneath all columns are used

Answer (score 3):

Luke Ludwig of TST Media offers a solution [here](http://pulse.sportngin.com/news_article/show/85364?referrer_id=308069). Essentially they "override the ActiveRecord::Base.columns method on the class whose column is being removed."

(solution applicable to all but 3.1)

Comment: Well if you downvote everyone who tries to help but is not what you need I imagine you will have a lot takers

Comment: Oh and in the page I linked to they are in AR 3.0.5

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple application servers so that you can take one down at a time without downtime, the following will work:

1. Remove the ability for users to modify the columns you are removing.
2. Restart applications one at a time.
3. Start up a new database that is a master-master to your existing database.
4. Stop replication from your new database.
5. Drop your columns on the new database server.
6. One at a time reconfigure each application server to use the new database server and restart.
7. Turn replication back on for your new database.
8. Once the original server has caught back up, reconfigure the applications to use that database server again (with applicable restarts).
9. Stop replication and turn off new database server.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I hoped to find a way to do it without heavy DB lifting